# Why all jwplayer Commands are not working in smart TVs

Tags: html, video, jwplayer, smart-tv

I had been asked the following question in this platform.
[Is there a CE-HTML based tool for playing video on Smart TV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22166780/is-there-a-ce-html-based-tool-for-playing-video-on-smart-tv).

The following rewind and fast forward commonds are not working in smart tv, while it is working fine in my computer's browser

```
jwp.seek(Math.max(0, parseInt(jwp.getPosition()) - 10))
jwp.seek(Math.min(jwp.getDuration(), parseInt(jwp.getPosition()) + 10))
```

Am I doing something wrong in my code. If so, how can I make my JWPlayer work well in my Smart TV web application.

Comment: We never test against these devices officially, sorry.

Comment: What smart tv you use exactly? What video type are you playing?

Comment: philps smart tv and the extension of video is mp4.